# How to make notifications appear during the week and only at certain times?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I want that app user receive notifications for example Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday at 10:45. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use AlarmManager. Initialize it in your start activity. Create BroadcastReciever to handle notifications. Change your Manifest file.

Here is [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583280/set-notification-for-specific-date-and-time)