# Android 8/9 Notification scheduling

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I have tried to schedule notifications for a specific date and time, but on majority of devices it seems that the notifications are not showing up. Before android 9/8 I have used AlarmManager which was pretty easy to use and it worked but the last 2 versions of android have changed this...(thanks google for making everything easier...)
So, here is my code that I use to schedule the notification. I'm using `OneTimeWorkRequest`

```
tag = new AlertsManager(this).getCarId(nrInmatriculare);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

    Data inputData = new Data.Builder().putString("type", alarmType).putString("nrInmatriculare", nrInmatriculare).build();

    OneTimeWorkRequest notificationWork = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotifyWorker.class)
            .setInitialDelay(calculateDelay(when), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setInputData(inputData)
            .addTag(String.valueOf(tag))
            .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(notificationWork);
}
else {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), pendingIntent);
}
```

Then the class that I'm using to show the notification is this:

```
public class NotifyWorker extends Worker {

    public NotifyWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Worker.Result doWork() {
        // Method to trigger an instant notification


        new NotificationIntentService().showNotification(getInputData().getString("type"),getInputData().getString("nrInmatriculare"), getApplicationContext());

        return Worker.Result.SUCCESS;
        // (Returning RETRY tells WorkManager to try this task again
        // later; FAILURE says not to try again.)
    }
}
```

and this one :

```
public class NotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
    final Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    int alarmId = 0;


    public NotificationIntentService() {
        super("NotificationIntentService");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            showNotification(intent);
    }

    //show notification with workmanager
    public void showNotification(String type, String nrInmatriculare, Context context){
        try
        {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(type) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(nrInmatriculare)) {

                AlertsManager alertsManager = new AlertsManager(context);
                Notifications notification = alertsManager.getAlertForCar(nrInmatriculare);
                String text ="";
                Calendar endDate = null;
                String date = notification.EndDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + (notification.EndDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)/10==0 ? "0"+(notification.EndDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) : (notification.EndDate.get(Calendar.MONTH))+1) + "-" + (notification.EndDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)/10==0 ? "0"+notification.EndDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) : notification.EndDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                text = context.getString(R.string.notificationText).toString().replace("#type#", type.toUpperCase()).replace("#nrInmatriculare#", nrInmatriculare).replace("#date#", date ).replace("#days#", String.valueOf(new Utils().getDateDifferenceInDays(Calendar.getInstance(), notification.EndDate)));
                alarmId = alertsManager.getCarId(nrInmatriculare);
                endDate = (Calendar)notification.EndDate.clone();

                if (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() > endDate.getTimeInMillis()){ //current time is after the end date (somehow the alarm is fired)
                }
                else {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        //define the importance level of the notification
                        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                        //build the actual notification channel, giving it a unique ID and name
                        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("AppName", "AppName", importance);
                        //we can optionally add a description for the channel
                        String description = "A channel which shows notifications about events at Masina";
                        channel.setDescription(description);
                        //we can optionally set notification LED colour
                        channel.setLightColor(Color.MAGENTA);

                        // Register the channel with the system
                        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.
                                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        if (notificationManager != null) {
                            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                        }

                        //---------

                        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "AppName");
                        builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
                        builder.setContentText(text);
                        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
                        builder.setLights(Color.CYAN, 1000, 2000);
                        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
                        builder.setSound(notificationSound);
                        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(text));
                        Intent notifyIntent = null;
                        if (type.equals("CarteDeIdentitate") || type.equals("PermisDeConducere"))
                            notifyIntent = new Intent(context, PersonalDataActivity.class);
                        else
                            notifyIntent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                        notifyIntent.putExtra("car", new SharedPreference(context).getCarDetailString(nrInmatriculare));
                        // Create the TaskStackBuilder and add the intent, which inflates the back stack
                        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
                        stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(notifyIntent);
                        //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, alarmId, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(alarmId, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        //to be able to launch your activity from the notification
                        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                        //trigger the notification
                        NotificationManagerCompat notificationAlert = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
                        notificationManager.notify(alarmId, builder.build());
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("here","No extra");
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("here","Error");
        }
    }

}
```

what am I doing wrong? there is a best and more efficient way of doing this?

EDIT: 
I would like to see an example about how to schedule a notification to a specific date + time, that really works.

Comment: "some devices" might have the notification channel muted.

Comment: I have talked with some users about this problem. They have allowed all the permissions and they didn't muted the notifications

Comment: this is still quite a theoretical question, without defining what "some devices" are... those worker jobs are guaranteed to be executed - while it is not guaranteed, that the job it runs will function on any device. this check for `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O` is also redundant, because WorkManager handles the scheduling all by itself, internally.

Comment: One small question, you have you made your `NotificationIntentService` as Intent Service but is initializing it in `doWork` of `NotifyWorker`.

Comment: This means android has no idea you have started a new service and because your app might be empty (means no activity/service running), android can kill it without having to worry about anything.

Comment: NotificationIntentService is declared in the AndroidManifest.xml as service
        <service
            android:name=".NotificationIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />
As you can see the Notifyworker is implementing the doWork method

Comment: by initializing I meant you are not doing start service. By calling constructor directly to make a object does not mean it will be started as a service.

Comment: then how to initialize it ?

Comment: in `NotifyWorker` you have ref. to context. so you can use it to do context.startService(intentToStartService)

Comment: any reason are you starting new service for notification ? you can put notification code direct there . Worker it self running in background .  @Coder

Comment: added start service code below please check @Coder

Comment: there are a lot of possibilities here. please try a much simpler notification, and try some easier task in do work to see if that part works. and let us know

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one working implementation that I've used in one of my project.

Add this to your `build.gradle (app)` (Since  it's in Kotlin)

```
//android-jet pack
implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx:1.0.1'
```

or using Android X:

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.5.0"
```

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work

Create a method `scheduleNotification`.
Pass your necessary data

```
fun scheduleNotification(timeDelay: Long, tag: String, body: String) {

    val data = Data.Builder().putString("body", body)

    val work = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationSchedule>()
                .setInitialDelay(timeDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .setConstraints(Constraints.Builder().setTriggerContentMaxDelay(Constant.ONE_SECOND, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build()) // API Level 24
                .setInputData(data.build())
                .addTag(tag)
                .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(work)
}
```

`NotificationSchedule` Class

```
class NotificationSchedule (var context: Context, var params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val data = params.inputData
        val title = "Title"
        val body = data.getString("body")

        TriggerNotification(context, title, body)

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

`TriggerNotification` Class. Customize this class according to your need

```
class TriggerNotification(context: Context, title: String, body: String) {

init {
    sendNotification(context, title, body)
}

private fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context, name: String, description: String): String {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    val chanelId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel = NotificationChannel(chanelId, name, importance)
        channel.enableLights(true)
        channel.enableVibration(true)
        channel.description = description
        channel.lightColor = Color.BLUE
        channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
       
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    return chanelId
}

private fun sendNotification(context: Context, title: String, body: String) {

    val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
    val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, createNotificationChannel(context, title, body))
    val notificationId = (System.currentTimeMillis() and 0xfffffff).toInt()

    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setTicker("Hearty365")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentInfo("Content Info")
            .setAutoCancel(true)

    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build())
}


}
```

Comment: will this work for notifications that needs to be delayed for months?

Comment: Definitely, just change the TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS to TimeUnit.DAYS and pass your delay days  .setInitialDelay(30, TimeUnit.DAYS)

Comment: and after device reboot? :P

Comment: It works after device reboot. It maintains its task with its own db
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/archive/arch#workmanager_12

Comment: work manager working while the app is run, scheduled work will postpone to the next app start.

Comment: If i wanted to delete or update a  scheduled notification how can i do so using this code above?

Comment: @OumaimaAbouElMawahib like this WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWorkByTag("Your custom tag")

Answer (score 6):

Try below code, i have used it in one of my application which works fine for me.

```
private void startWorkForWeekNotification() {
    OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(
        OpenAppNotifyWorker.class)
        .setInitialDelay(OpenAppNotifyWorker.NOTIFY_TO_OPEN_APP_IN_DAYS, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance().beginUniqueWork(
        OpenAppNotifyWorker.WORKER_NAME,
        ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
        oneTimeWorkRequest).enqueue();
}
```

Worker Class

```
public class OpenAppNotifyWorker extends Worker {

public static final String WORKER_NAME = "OpenAppNotifyWorker";

public static final int NOTIFY_TO_OPEN_APP_IN_DAYS = 7;

public OpenAppNotifyWorker(@NonNull Context context,
    @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    NotificationUtils
        .showNotification(getApplicationContext(), NotificationUtils.UPDATE_CHANNEL_ID,
            NotificationUtils.UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_ID);
    return Result.success();
}

}
```

NotificationUtils Class

```
public class NotificationUtils {

public static final String UPDATE_CHANNEL_ID = "updates";

public static final int UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

public static final int NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE = 50;

public static void showNotification(Context context, String channelId, int notificationId) {
    createNotificationChannel(context, channelId);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        context, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_splash_logo)
        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.title_notification))
        .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.msg_body_notification))
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat
        .from(context);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
}

public static void createNotificationChannel(Context context, String channelId) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        //TODO change channel name and description
        CharSequence name = context.getString(R.string.notification_channel_updates);
        String description = context.getString(R.string.desc_notification_channel);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
            channelId, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = context
            .getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}

public static void createPushNotification(Context context, String message) {
    NotificationUtils
        .createNotificationChannel(context, NotificationUtils.UPDATE_CHANNEL_ID);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(FcmPushListenerService.EXTRAS_NOTIFICATION_DATA, message);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent
        .getActivity(context, NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        context, NotificationUtils.UPDATE_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_app_logo)
        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText(message)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat
        .from(context);
    notificationManager.notify(NotificationUtils.UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}

public static void cancelAllNotification(Context context) {
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat
        .from(context);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
}
```

if you want to start service you can do that by following :

```
public class OpenAppNotifyWorker extends Worker {

public static final String WORKER_NAME = "OpenAppNotifyWorker";

public static final int NOTIFY_TO_OPEN_APP_IN_DAYS = 7;

public Context context;

public OpenAppNotifyWorker(@NonNull Context context,
@NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    this.context = context
    super(context, workerParams);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    context.startService(new NotificationIntentService())
    return Result.success();
}

}
```